# Why are all textareas being updated onchange?

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I'm trying to add a placeholder in the `descrip` `<textarea>` if the related `process` `<textarea>` is not empty. However, when I type some text in any `process` `<textarea>` a placeholder is added to **all** of my `descrip` `<textarea>`'s.

I think it has something to do with how I'm selecting the `descrip` `<textarea>`'s in my `querySelectorAll`. However, in my project I do the exact same thing with radio buttons and it works just fine.

I've written my loop using `.forEach` *and* with a standard `for-loop`, but I still get the same result.

Below is a replicable example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```js
const processes = document.querySelectorAll(".process > textarea");
const descrips = document.querySelectorAll(".descrip > textarea");

function descError() {
 for (var i = 0; i < processes.length; i++){
   if(processes[i] != ""){
     descrips[i].placeholder = "Describe";
   } else{
     descrips[i].placeholder = "";
   }
 }
}

processes.forEach((proc) => proc.addEventListener("change", descError));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="process" ><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td class="descrip"><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="process"><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td class="descrip"><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="process"><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td class="descrip"><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `if(processes[i].value != ""){` - possibly even `if(processes[i].value.trim() !== ""){`

Comment: You're also adding the event listener to each process textarea, then the event listener itself is looping through all of them; might make more sense to only add the placeholder to the targeted textareas, rather than loop through all.

Comment: try to use let in place of var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo - missing .value

This is more elegant - using delegation

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("input", e => {
  const tgt = e.target; 
  if (tgt.closest("td").matches(".process")) { 
    tgt.closest("tr").querySelector(".descrip textarea").placeholder = tgt.value.trim() === "" ? "" : "Describe";
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td class="process"><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td class="descrip"><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="process"><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td class="descrip"><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="process"><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td class="descrip"><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very nice. I like this. Thanks!